# me muestra IndentationError: expected an indented block en spider - estoy trabajando con una base de datos tipo csv con Kmeans

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, max_iter=300)
    kmeans.fit(vinos_norm)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

> IndentationError: expected an indented block
>
> - Tambien muestra esto:
>
> - NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: No parecen estar esos errores en el código que muestras. Podrías agregar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en donde ocurra ese error por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Este fallo tiene que ver con la sintaxis del programa que has escrito, no con el funcionamiento. En concreto, parece que has puesto en algún sitio del codigo un espacio que no esperaba ver. Eso sí, el trozo de código que has pegado no contiene los fallos que dices.

¿es esto todo lo que estás ejecutando? ¿Puedes copiar todo el código?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).